# Creating a class that handles postgresql queries in C#

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, methods

My question is: What's the most efficient way to handle bunch of  postgresql queries inside a new class/method that have different SQL queries, parameters and return values?

For example:

```
NpgsqlCommand ukupno_sati = new NpgsqlCommand("begin;select cast(radni_sati.sati_rada as time) from radni_sati where zaposlenik_id=@zaposlenik_id " +
                    " and extract(month from radni_sati.datum)=@mjesec_broj and extract(year from radni_sati.datum)=@godina;commit;",conn);
                    ukupno_sati.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zaposlenik_id", dtIme_prezime_odjel_bolovanje_godisnji.Rows[i][0]);
                    ukupno_sati.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mjesec_broj", mjesec_broj);
                    ukupno_sati.Parameters.AddWithValue("@godina", godina);
                    NpgsqlDataAdapter dz = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(ukupno_sati);
                    DataTable UkupnoSati = new DataTable();
                    dz.Fill(UkupnoSati);
```

or

```
NpgsqlCommand godisnji = new NpgsqlCommand("begin;select count(*) from godisnji where extract(month from godisnji.datum)" +
                    "=@mjesec_broj and extract(year from godisnji.datum)=@godina and zaposlenik_id=@zaposlenik_id;commit;",conn);
                    godisnji.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mjesec_broj", mjesec_broj.ToString());
                    godisnji.Parameters.AddWithValue("@godina", godina.ToString());
                    godisnji.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zaposlenik_id", dtIme_prezime_odjel_bolovanje_godisnji.Rows[i][0]);
                    int iskoristeni_godisnji = Convert.ToInt32(godisnji.ExecuteScalar());
```

So my point is: Can I make a method that handles different queries with different return values and different number of parameters depending on a queries like shown in examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same technique I've used for writing [ADONETHelper](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper).
Also, check out the code on the project that's called HowToUseADONETHelper.

The main method is this:

```
T Execute<T>(string sql, CommandType commandType, Func<IDbCommand, T> function, params IDbDataParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (var con = new TConnection()) // replace TConnection with your connection object
    {
        con.ConnectionString = _ConnectionString;
        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand()) 
        {
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = commandType;
            if (parameters.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }
            }
            con.Open();
            return function(cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the Execute method accepts an argument of type `Func<IDbCommand, T>` - that fact allows you to do all kind of interesting things:

Then you can use some other execute overloads to simplify your code:

Execute non query:

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, CommandType commandType, params IDbDataParameter[] parameters)
{
    return Execute<int>(sql, commandType, c => c.ExecuteNonQuery(), parameters);
}
```

That's pretty simple - the function you send to the `Execute` method is simply `c => c.ExecuteNonQuery()` - and as you know, the ExecuteNonQuery in the IDbCommand interface is returning an `int`, so `Execute` will also return `int`.

Execute Scalar:

```
public T ExecuteScalar<T>(string sql, CommandType commandType, params IDbDataParameter[] parameters)
{
    return Execute<T>(sql, commandType, c =>
    {
        var returnValue = c.ExecuteScalar();
        return (returnValue != null && returnValue != DBNull.Value && returnValue is T)
         ? (T)returnValue
         : default(T);
    }, parameters);
}
```

Here the function is a little more complicated. The `ExecuteScalar()` of `IDbCommand` returns an `Object`. That `Object` might be null, it might be DBNull, or it might be a string, int, or whatever datatype supported by your database. So what I do is use a condition that returns the `default` of `T` when the value returned by `ExecuteScalar` is `null` or `DBNull`, or simply cast the `object` to `T` and return it.

Execute Reader:

```
// Here, you do the actuall reading from the dataReader in the populate function
public bool ExecuteReader(string sql, CommandType commandType, Func<IDataReader, bool> populate, params IDbDataParameter[] parameters)
{
    return Execute<bool>(sql, commandType, c => populate(c.ExecuteReader()), parameters);
}
```

Pretty simple, right? the populate function might look something like this:

```
bool Populate(IDataReader reader)
{
     var obj = new MyClass();
     while(reader.Read())
     {
         obj.PropertyA = reader.GetValueOrDefault("A"); // That method is written in the IDataReaderExtestion class in ADONETHelper
     }

    return true;
}
```

And fill a dataset:

```
public DataSet FillDataSet(string sql, CommandType commandType, params IDbDataParameter[] parameters)
{
    return Execute<DataSet>(sql, commandType, c => FillDataSet(c), parameters);
}

private DataSet FillDataSet(IDbCommand command)
{
    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    using (var adapter = new TAdapter())
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
    }
    return dataSet;
}
```

Basically, I could have done the same thing here as with the execute reader, and write the `FillDataSet` method as a lambda expression, I don't remember why I've decided to write the `FillDataSet` as a different method. However, this is the method I pass as the `function` argument to the `Execute` method. It simply use a DataAdapter to fill the dataset. Note that you should change the `TAdapter` to `NpgsqlDataAdapter` in your case.

Comment: Love ur answer, would like to see more commented code if possible, coz I can copy/paste/modify it without understanding some parts, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Main thing im confused about is "Execute Scalar" and "dataset", don't understand some parts of return call in those methods so if you would be so kind to comment those parts, would be grateful =)

Comment: @MarkoPetričević I've added some explanations in my answer. Is there anything else you want me to explain?

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate this.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: I have one question if ur still willing to help: My main method looks like this:

`T Execute<T>(string sql, CommandType commandType, Func<NpgsqlCommand, T> function, params NpgsqlParameterCollection[] parameters)`

Now the problem I have is that when I do:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterName,parameterValue)`

I cannot do it coz every parameter has to have  a name and an object that it refers to, any idea how to make this collection take parameters with those 2 arguments?

Comment: You send the parameters to the function as an array of `NpgsqlParameter` (or as a single `NpgsqlParameterCollection`) Look at [Working with ADONETHelper wiki page](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper/wiki/Working-with-ADONETHelper) for code samples.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to return Data Table and integer from a method then its possible in single method by using data table as return type and integer as out parameter(you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier))

Comment: Its Data Table OR integer OR something else, in rare cases I will have to return both of them, but thanks for info.