# How to create a single repository for all queries using ADO.net and MVC

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, npgsql

since im using npgsql and postgressql creating model from my database is a big pain,there are man views and adding views to model using npgsql is a big pain which is not solved yet,any way for some reasons I need to use ado,is there any possibility to have a single gate for all my transactions?i have the following code in my controller:

Here I have my connection:

```
                NpgsqlConnection npgc = new NpgsqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Central"].ConnectionString);
                                                                    npgc.Open();
                                                                    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"SELECT xc.m_error_group_name, xc.m_error_group_id, count(*),error_duration
                                                                    FROM (
                                                                    SELECT extract(year from m_date) m_year, v1.m_error_group_name,  v1.m_error_group_id, 
                                                                   zd.t_users g on(g.user_id=f.pv_person_resp_id) and g.user_name in(@rgnal)
                                                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN ssw_mdt.t_master_pc_alarm_pattern t3 ON (t1.m_inv_error_details = t3.pc_group_pattern)
                                                                   WHERE (m_date between @fr and @to) 
                                                                   AND t1.crew_present is FALSE
                                                                   AND t1.m_grid_loss is FALSE
                                                                   ) GROUP BY 1, 2
                                                                  order by error_duration desc", npgc);
```

here is how I query:

```
        NpgsqlParameter[] param = {new NpgsqlParameter("@rgnal",reginalManagers), 
                                      new NpgsqlParameter("@fr",dtFrom),
                                     new NpgsqlParameter("@to",dtTo);
                                     cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
                                     FaultStatViewModel flt = new FaultStatViewModel();
                                     using (NpgsqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                                      {
                                          while (rdr.Read())
                                          {

                                              flt.m_error_group_name.Add(rdr["m_error_group_name"].ToString());
                                          }
                                      }

                                      npgc.Close();
```

so imagine I have 10 other queries I don't want to do these all again and again,please help me out,im new

Comment: If you insist asking the wrong question, you'll always get a wrong answer. Creating an EF model from your database isn't a pain but the question you ask isn't relevant. If you want a *repository* how you write the query isn't relevant. This is a plain old ADO.NET question, not related to repositories at all - `How do I use DbCommands in ADO.NET` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF/Postgres SQL database-first approach possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394760/ef-postgres-sql-database-first-approach-possible)

Comment: Anyway, saying that creating 30 classes is painful but writing 30 embedded queries isn't, is rather strange

Comment: Another [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478480/postgresql-data-provider-missing-from-wizard-in-visual-studio-2015) points to [Npgsql's Visual Studio Integration](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html) including a model generator

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if I use 30 different class then I I have 30 times npgsqlconnection in my codes,plus npgsql if tou add views to your model you will see how many errors you get,like:yout table/view has been automatically excluded,and also you can not add stored procedure,thats why I have to use ado

Comment: No you won't. You will have only *one* DbContext hence only *one* connection. And yes, you can map views to objects. No, you don't have to use ADO just to avoid writing the code for a few classes. Writing 30 queries is harder. Creating a repository without actually understanding what a repository is, and getting it right is impossible

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so your suggestion is to avoid ado ?

Comment: If you insist on using basic ADO.Net and not EF, you can use [something like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601828/creating-a-class-that-handles-postgresql-queries-in-c-sharp/46602336#46602336)